# Elastic search multi index query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am building an app where I need to match users based on several parameters. I have two elastic search indexes, one with the user's likes and dislikes, one with some metadata about the user.

```
/user_profile/abc12345

{
"userId": "abc12345",
"likes": ["chocolate", "vanilla", "strawberry"]
}
```

```
/user_metadata/abc12345
{
"userId": "abc12345",
"seenBy": ["aaa123","bbb123", "ccc123"] // Potentially hundreds of thousands of userIds
}
```

I was advised to make these separate indexes and cross reference them, but how do I do that? For example I want to search for a user who likes `chocolate` and has NOT been seen by user `abc123`. How do I write this query?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a frequent query in your use case, I would recommend merging the indices (always design your indices based on your queries).

Anyhow, a possible workaround for your current scenario is to exploit the fact that both indices store the user identifier in a field with the same name (`userId`). Then, you can (1) issue a boolean query over both indices, to match documents from one index based on the `likes` field, and documents from the other index based on the `seenBy` field, (2) use the [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) bucket aggregation to get the list of unique `userId`s that satisfy your conditions.

For example

```
GET user_*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "likes": "chocolate"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "seenBy": "abc123"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_userId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userId.keyword",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do you think there would be any performance implications for adding a potentially large field to the `user_profile` index?

Comment: Not for the use case you described. I'd say you have more performance implications when querying two indices and aggregating over their responses.